# Compare tables on different servers

Tags: java, sql-server

Using java and SQL Server 2008, I need to compare the content of two tables, the thing to bear in mind is that they are on different servers so I have a connection to the first server (lets call it conn1) and a connection to the second server (lets call it conn2). 
I copy the tables into temp tables and then attempt to use the EXCEPT operator to compare the temp tables.

A very basic example of trying to do this in java:

```
String s1 = "select * into #temp1 from FACTOR";
String s2 = "select * into #temp2 from FACTOR'";
String s3 = "SELECT * FROM #temp1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM #temp2";

Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
st = conn1.createStatement();
st.execute(s1);

Statement st1 = null;
ResultSet rs1 = null;
st1 = conn2.createStatement();
st1.execute(s2);

Statement st3 = null;
ResultSet rs3 = null;
st3 = conn2.createStatement();
rs3 = st3.executeQuery(s3);
```

I'm getting the following error on the last line in the above code snippet:

```
Stack trace:java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name '#temp1'.
```

Is it because I'm using the two connections to the different servers, conn2 can't see #temp1?

Any ideas how I could acheive what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do doesn't make sense.  Remember that the SQL gets executed on the SQL Server, not in Java. So if the 2 SQL Servers cant see each other, you cant execute queries across SQL Servers that cant see each other.

One solution is to execute the queries on both the servers, and get the data into Java  `ResultSet`, and then process the data in java.

alternatively, copy all the data to one SQL Server, and do your EXCEPT query on that Server

Answer (score 0):

If the SQL Servers can "see" each other, then you can do the whole thing from one connection:

```
"SELECT * FROM Server1.database.schema.FACTOR
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Server2.database.schema.Factor"
```

I would suggest listing the column names in case they change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Normal Temp tables are only visible to the connection they are used within. Global temp tables denoted by'##' instead of '#' are visible to multiple connections but disappear when the connection that created them is closed.

This would be better done in a stored procedure using a linked server. e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspCompareTables
AS
BEGIN
     select * from Factor
     EXCEPT
     select * from OTHER_SERVER.dbo.Factor
END
```

Then you can just call it from your java application. using the normal...

```
exec uspCompareTables
```